# Warning: Illegal string offset 'userid' in [path]/includes/functions.php on line 509

Tags: php, vbulletin

I recently upgraded PHP to 5.4 and now I started getting error. I'm using vBulletin 3.8.4

Here is the code:

```
if (!is_array($user_memberships["$userinfo[userid]]") OR !$cache)
```

Other lines with error

```
1) $user_memberships["$userinfo[userid]"] = fetch_membergroupids_array($userinfo);

2) if ($user['membergroupids'])

3) $membergroups = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $user['membergroupids']));

4) $membergroups[] = $user['usergroupid'];
```

Comment: `$user_memberships["$userinfo[userid]]"` should be `$user_memberships[$userinfo['userid']]`, no?

Comment: Still the same error, also tried removing ' didn't work